# Account wide api keys in a many to many scenario

Tags: rest, symfony, security, api-design

I'm in the process of developing a REST API where users are able to have multiple accounts. User will be able to access the API via JWT authentication and accounts will have API keys allowing you to perform CRUD operations on models related to the account (Account and models are related in a one-to-many fashion).

My question is how one would implement this in a secure way? Stripe has similar logic and the API keys associated with an account are visible to all users connected to it, leading me to think they might be stored in plaintext or encrypted with a common key?

I also can't seem to wrap my head around how one would create a single controller endpoint that uses either a jwt token or an account specific api key.

I'm thinking it could be done by requiring an account_id on requests performed with the JWT and loading this automatically on API key requests but would this be the best approach or am I missing something?

Something along the lines of

```
public function createModel(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->type === 'api_key')
        $account_id = $this->getAccountIdFromKey($request->get('api_key'));
    } else {
        //Request is performed using user JWT
        //Validate that $request has account_id set
    }

    //Logic related to saving Model here
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can store the account id in the JWT payload when you issue it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into this example, it describes how to use a api key to authenticate a user via the Symfony Security component [Official Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/api_key_authentication.html).

I could not find the documentation for the 4.* version of Symfony, it should be much different for that Version.

Or you could include the [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) which provides a complete support for a JWT authentication process.